# Do larger Javascript functions take longer to define?

Tags: javascript, performance, v8

Do larger (longer, more complex) JS functions take longer to define? (BTW this isn't about the time it takes to invoke a function)

Comment: Define "define"

Comment: You mean interpret? Of course, the parser has to parse every single character in your source code, any extra character means extra parsing. But note that this only happens on script load and it's not really affecting performance in any way, mostly the performance would be affected by downloading that longer function than parsing and interpreting it.

Comment: "let f = function(){ }" vs "let f = function(){ let a = null; }", the second one is a bit more complex, does it take js engines longer to run the second line? Assuming that neither function gets invoked.

Comment: A. Yes B. Google: "Eric lippert which is faster" - enjoy!

Comment: I could be wrong, don't JS engines parse the entire file prior to actually instantiating any objects defined in the file? In which case shouldn't the slowdown caused by a longer JS file only happen once during the parsing phase?

Comment: @LaiXue So you want to know if creating a new function in JS takes longer if that function is longer? Common sense might say that yes, it's impossible for a longer function object to take *less* time to create than a shorter function (where more complex means more instructions)

Comment: @Cristy If the compiler ignores content inside of the function until the function is invoked, then there shouldn't be a difference

Comment: As was said above, since the source code is longer, *parsing* will take longer. Beyond that the engine may or may not *do* anything with that parsed code at the time of parsing, or at the time of first invocation, or sometime inbetween. It will have to take longer *at some point*. But really, unless you have megabytes and megabytes of code, you'll hardly ever see any difference in practice; coupled with the fact that different engines will do different things this isn't a very productive question.

Comment: I tried this: https://plnkr.co/edit/BAbUXAls5Mfp1ABm96Tn and the speed seems to be the same for both tests. `test1.js` defines a function that returns an empty array, `test2.js` defines a function that inits 200 elements of an array and returns it. not sure if that is what you mean by complex though.

Answer (score 0):

My point:

Larger function takes more time for JavaScript engine to process it.

> For JavaScript, the compilation that occurs happens, in many cases, mere microseconds (or less!) before the code is executed.

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch1.md#compiler-theory

Hope you can find something helpful here. :-)